# Get filename from an inputstream (Java)

Tags: java, inputstream, java-me

if I have this code, how could I keep the filename of the original file or reassign it to the new one?:

```
    InputStream input= assetInfo.openStream();
    File t = new File("");

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(t);

    int read=0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while((read = input.read(bytes))!= -1){
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An input stream can be created to read from a file or from any other source of data. Therefore it makes no sense to have a filename attached to an input stream. Look in `assetInfo` to see if that class exposes that data (you can even look inside the class using reflection). Note that the creator or `assetInfo` made a design mistake not exposing this information, OR you are trying to make one now.